# "is much a news in the moment"?

Tags: british-english, speech

I'm trying to understand what is said in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAV_0s1c2V4) between 00:27 and 00:35...

I can understand the beginning, "With religion, community relations and tolerance", but... And then?

I'm listening this part for about 20 minutes, and the closest i could get was "is much a news in the moment"... And if I'm not mistaken, this can not be right... And the rest of this part, (00:27-00:35) I didn't understand absolutely nothing...

Can you guys help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as helpful as we'd like to be, we are not a transcription service for random video / audio clips.

Comment: @Hellion Yes, I know this is not a "transcription service for random videos / audio clips"... But I believe it is a service to help others who are trying to learn english... And listening is a very important part of understand a language... With all due respect, i can not view this question as off topic, and you really are not being helpful at all...

Comment: see this question on our Meta site:  http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/exactly-why-is-this-question-off-topic-or-not/5369#5369

Comment: Ok, I understand you don't like helping others with listening using the excuse that is not a "transcription service"... I'm sorry, but this is what it looks like... Your answer in a question from 2014 don't make this a real reason for close this question as "off-topic"... I'm not asking for "free transcription service"... I'm asking for help, because a difficult with understanding the pronunciation of a few words... Because a difficult with "listening"... And close a question of listening on a service which was supposed to help others with English, I'm sorry, but dont make sense at all...

Comment: Hi Ricardo.  **IT IS JUST A MISTAKE** .. a "verbal typo". that's all there is to it, it's of zero consequence. the common phrase is simply "much in the news at the moment".  people misspeak all the time, it's of utterly no consequence whatsoever.

Comment: I can hear: *“...community relations and* **tolerance** *much in (the) news at the moment”*. It's perfectly grammatical :)

Comment: As much as I sympathise with your difficulty, these types of questions have to be off topic. If we allowed one, then before you know it, people will be asking users to decipher pop / hip hop songs; street interviews, radio programmes, standup comedians etc.

Comment: Quite right, as ML says.

Answer (score 1):

Having watched the video, I confirm that others' suspicions are correct: the speaker is saying "much in the news at the moment", but he sort of swallows the "in the" part. If you look closely, though, you can see that he does move his lips in two separate movements. The unclarity is easy to understand, if you consider that the transition from "in" to "the" is performed almost exclusively with the tongue.

Answer (score 0):

OP, be aware that

> "is much in the news at the moment.."

is a completely common phrase in English.

It's absolutely commonplace that commentators talk in a very messy manner, on TV and videos. In particularly, it's utterly common that they mess-up (often in ahumorous way) idiomatic phrases.

IF the reader said it incorrectly (so, omitting or substituting a word), there's just nothing to this other than a "verbal typo" .. a misspeaking.  OK?

You now know what the common phrase is.

This is an ESL question!

Comment: Listen again....

Comment: Hi ML.  Fair, but honestly I don't have time.  OP should go to ESL site. Fact: "is much in the news at the moment.." is a common phrase in English.  I can't help anymore here but am ready to supply my usual subtleties on any worthy questions arising tonight.

Comment: ~~ smiley ~~ ...

Comment: Then you shouldn't have answered. And this question is off topic on ELL as well. :)

Comment: Wait ......... why did you command me to "listen again"???  My answer is **precisely the same as the answer you gave in a comment**!  Geesh

Comment: No, it's not. "**TOLERANCE** much in the news...." There's no "is"

Comment: Talk about a tiny argument!  :)  as I said the newsreaders SHOULD HAVE SAID "blah is much in the news at the moment".  I appreciate I used "typo" in sentence 1 and "verbal typo" in sentence 3.  The utterly key point is that the OP does not know that "is much in the news at the moment.." is a common English phrase.  Secondly, the OP should be aware that it's utterly common for phrases to be more or less mangled by the sort of joker that does videos and news broadcasts.

Comment: OK, so if Penelope Keith said something incorrectly in a read, it would be worth a question.